# Why can't I adjust my div's position

Tags: css

Basically I am using the "Tryit Editor" from the W3 website and
this is the code I started out with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
body
{
background-image:url("img_tree.gif"),url("img_flwr.gif");
background-color:#cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to change the background color and background images so that they were only found on a div, not on the whole page. I also wanted to move the div around the page. I was able to make the div with the background elements, but I wasn't able to move it around the page. I used the following code, thinking that

```
top:150px;
left: 150px;
```

would have caused the div to change position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div 
{
position=fixed;
top:150px;
left: 150px;
background-image:url("img_tree.gif"),url("img_flwr.gif");
background-color:#00dccc;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alas, the div did not change position. What gives?

Thanks! :]

Comment: `position=fixed` should be `position:fixed`, obviously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an equals sign rather than a colon in your `position` declaration which is causing the page to ignore it. Change that and it'll work!

EDIT: Thanks for fixing my awful terminology Pavlo, can't believe I did that :P

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong. It should be

```
position: fixed;
```